Error loading Hugging Face model: SafeTensorsInfo.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sharded'
I have been using Hugging Face transformers quantized Llama2 model. Suddenly, code I was able to run earlier today is throwing an error when I try to load the model.
This code is straight from the docs:
from awq import AutoAWQForCausalLM
from transformers import AutoTokenizer

model_name_or_path = "TheBloke/Llama-2-7b-Chat-AWQ"

# Load model
model = AutoAWQForCausalLM.from_quantized(
    model_name_or_path,
    fuse_layers = True,
    trust_remote_code = False,
    safetensors = True
)

This suddenly generates this error:
TypeError: SafeTensorsInfo.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sharded'

The bizarre thing is that I was able to run this code earlier today on the same machine. It is the same model. I haven't installed or updated any new Python (or other) packages.
This is using Ubuntu 20.04. Here are the relevant package versions:
accelerate==0.28.0
autoawq==0.2.4
autoawq_kernels==0.0.6
bitsandbytes==0.43.0
huggingface-hub==0.22.2
torch==2.2.2+cu121
torchaudio==2.2.2+cu121
torchvision==0.17.2+cu121
transformers==4.38.2

How can an error suddenly arise when I haven't changed anything? It might make sense of my cached version of the model was no longer available, and it had downloaded a newer version. The way that transformers downloads models is a bit mysterious to me, but the model files page doesn't indicate anything has changed. What can I do to return to the position I was in this morning when this code would run?

getting same error since past 30 minutes, it's strange but i was able to run it 1 hour ago. i tried multiple models awq models. removed cached model, reinstalled huggingface nothing worked.

@AdarshPatel seems to be a huggingface issue - see my answer

Update: real fix
According to the GitHub issue:

A fix has been deployed a few minutes ago. This should be fixed for everyone without updating any dependencies. Sorry again for the inconvenience and thanks everyone for your reactivity on this 

As this was a server-side issue, this should now be resolved without updating packages or code.
Hot fix
This should not be necessary but I'll leave it here in case anyone faces the same issue. A hot fix was posted about 40 minutes after my question:

Hey everyone, thanks for quickly reporting issues and suggesting a workaround. Failure is indeed due to a server-side change and we are discussing solutions to mitigate it. In the meantime, I opened #2190 to fix the issue client-side (which will make the class future-proof). To get an immediate fix, please install from this branch:

pip install git+https://github.com/huggingface/huggingface_hub@2186-fix-safetensors-info

Workarounds
If you cannot or do not want to update your local huggingface-hub, here are some workarounds.
Workaround 1: load from snapshot
I am able to resolve it for now by loading this model from cache. I had to look in the cache directory, which is ~/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--TheBloke--Llama-2-7b-Chat-AWQ/snapshots/. This contains snapshots in subdirectories, so I used the most recent one, which is a long hex string. The code to make it work is:
model_name_or_path = "~/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--TheBloke--Llama-2-7b-Chat-AWQ/snapshots/ee91097dc818c742d9b648147891dfadd9638ace"

# Load model
model = AutoAWQForCausalLM.from_quantized(model_name_or_path, fuse_layers=True,
                                          trust_remote_code=False, safetensors=True)

Workaround 2: Edit hf_api.py
This is from the GitHub issue page and I can't take credit for it:
Add sharded: None in the file hf_api.py. Like this :
@DataClass
class SafeTensorsInfo(dict):
    parameters: List[Dict[str, int]]
    total: int
    sharded: None
def post_init(self): # hack to make SafeTensorsInfo backward compatible
    self.update(asdict(self))

hf_api.py is a file in huggingface-hub. Its location will depend on how you installed it. For me it is /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/huggingface_hub. If you used pip you can find the location with pip show huggingface-hub.
